# How to secure ELMAH with Web API v2 when you have no UI, just a pure API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, elmah

I am trying to figure out how to secure ELMAH with Web API v2 when I have no UI, just an api.

Thanks,

OutOfTOuch

Comment: Would you please elaborate what you want ? or what do you by securing ELMAH with pure API? I have already implemented both in my project. No UI is needed at all.

Comment: I am wondering how you can secure ELMAH with WEB API v2 when you have no UI. http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/01/aspnet-session-hijacking-with-google.html

Comment: I am wondering how you would do this cause with no UI there is no login screen.